# Refraction using Three.CubeCamera

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

I'm trying to set up a refraction sphere in a-frame, following Mr. Lee Stemkoski's [example](https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Refraction.html). I've managed to get a reflection sphere, which is basically a strip of the cool [a-frame mirror component](https://github.com/alfa256/aframe-mirror-component).

The CubeCamera is created, and its renderTarget is extracted as envMap texture upon initialize:
**Init:**

```
this.refractionCamera = new THREE.CubeCamera( 0.5, 3000, 128);
this.el.object3D.add( this.refractionCamera );
this.refractionMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ 
        color: 0xffffff, 
        refractionRatio: 0.4, 
        envMap: this.refractionCamera.renderTarget.texture });
```

Update the cubemap on tick:
**tick:**

```
this.refractionCamera.updateCubeMap( AFRAME.scenes[0].renderer,                         
this.el.sceneEl.object3D );
this.mesh.material = this.refractionMaterial;
```

Of course, the image is mirrored, because of how the Three.CubeCamera works, so I tried to rotate the texture or flip it somehow, so I won't have a mirror.

As I see Lee Stemkoski is only using:

```
refractSphereCamera.renderTarget.mapping = new THREE.CubeRefractionMapping();
```

- I tried doing that on init, but nothing changes. Check out the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ncspy8x2/1/).
- Also, I tried offsetting the texture, or vertical flipping, but nothing [happens](https://jsfiddle.net/ncspy8x2/4/).

Any ideas what's wrong in my approaches?

Comment: if you want refraction, then why not to try `this.refractionCamera.renderTarget.texture.mapping =  THREE.CubeRefractionMapping;`?

Comment: @prisoner849 i'm kinda trying to achieve it it the first fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ncspy8x2/1/ , or do You mean something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do

```
refractSphereCamera.renderTarget.mapping = THREE.CubeRefractionMapping;
```

If you want refraction, it's better to do

```
refractSphereCamera.renderTarget.texture.mapping = THREE.CubeRefractionMapping;
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/xsk72efe/) example

Comment: You are right, I was trying to do the mapping on the renderTarget, not on the renderTarget.texture ! Thank You very much.

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski You're welcome. Thanks for pointing to the `new` keyword ) I've overlooked it in the the answer)

Comment: no problem, just wanted to avoid future confusion :), thanks once more !

Answer (score 1):

Lee Stemkoski's example was built four years ago for an older version of Three.js. His source code states `Date: July 2013 (three.js v59dev)`, but your fiddle is using v84.

You should look at [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=refraction#webgl_materials_cubemap_refraction) which is compatible with the latest version of Three.js. If you look at the source code, the implementation is much simpler now:

```
// Load textureCube, change mapping from reflection to refraction
var textureCube = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader().load( urls );
textureCube.mapping = THREE.CubeRefractionMapping;

// Assign textureCube to background
scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = textureCube;

// Use textureCube as environment map, which will use refraction mapping.
var cubeMaterial3 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xccddff, envMap: textureCube, refractionRatio: 0.98, reflectivity: 0.9 } );
```

Comment: You may want to update your example code to use the CubeCamera's renders as the textureCube's images rather than urls as that is specifically what the OP is asking help with. Also, the example is r60 of three.js as can be seen in the console.

Comment: 1. I do realize, that Lee Stemkoski's example is on an older version, hence i used (..).mapping = Three.CubeRefractonMapping, instead of 'new Three.CubeRefractionMapping()', ( in the first fiddle ) 2. I also know, that i can make the refraction on envMap texures, which is much more efficient then updating 6 cameras, and creating a envMap texture out of it. 3. so if You replace the textureCube with my CubeCamera.renderTarget, and throw out the background assigning, it seems to be the same as my first try ( first fiddle )